# Changing multiple files batch file doesnt work

Tags: batch-file

This is a very simple batch file I did to start practicing with the command line, but for some reason it wont work properly. Here the code:

```
::Change names

@echo off
set /p DirLoc = "Enter file location:"
cd %DirLoc%
echo %DirLoc%
dir
set /p SetFrom = "What file type is it?"
set /P SetTo = "What file type do you want?"
echo Change from %SetFrom%
echo to %SetTo%
rename *.%SetFrom% *.%SetTo%
echo process has been completed
pause

echo on
```

For some reason, when I insert the folder location, which in my case is "C:\Users\Marco DS\Desktop\Test", the program will only go till "C:\Users\Marco DS\Desktop", which is no good. I have tried a few alternatives of my entries, but I never manage to get the desired directory.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=` in your `set` [`/P`] command lines; otherwise they become part of the variable name...

Comment: Do I have to remove both spaces? Thanks!

Comment: For `set /P`, you must remove the left space, the right one does not matter; however, for `set` (without `/P`), you most remove both; so for the sake of consistency, I recommend to remove both even for `set /P`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is that, in Batch, you should not use spaces or quotation marks when setting variables, or else they will be part of the variable. Unlike many languages, Batch reads all whitespace characters as part of the code. In this case, the name of the variable is set as `%DirLoc %` instead of just `%DirLoc%`. In order to make your code work in the way you want, you need to remove all the unwanted spaces and quotation marks in your code.

For example: 
`set /p DirLoc = "Enter file location:"` becomes `set /p DirLoc=Enter file location:`

To see proof of this, try writing `echo %DirLoc %` right after `echo %DirLoc%` and running the code.